# how do i read/import images ,which is stored in my laptop, in google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

Whenever i specify them path like "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\tumor", I get the "file not found" error,using cv2.imread(). Can anyone explain the correct way to read them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to transfer files to the backend VM. Recipes are in the I/O example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb

Or, you can use a local runtime as described here:
http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html